# Windows Workflow 4.0 Activities not being added to the toolbox

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I've created a class project in VS 2010 Beta 2.  I've added one Activity to it.  Saved it.  Created another Activity.  I would expect the first Activity to appear in the toolbox so I could drag it into my workflow, but it's not.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2010 RTM as well. I wrote a blog post with a potential solution [here](http://www.rohland.co.za/index.php/2010/06/08/workflow-4-0-custom-activities-not-appearing-in-the-vs2010-toolbox/).

Essentially, the toolbox doesn't load your custom activities if you have two projects in your solution that share the same folder.

Comment: I almost dismissed this answer, it seemed too weird to be true. Turns out to be exactly correct... Go Microsoft!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I had an LLBLGenPro adapter project(s) just like the RP.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Custom Activity class is marked as public.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue too.  My workflow service project was part of a solution with other projects.  I removed the workflow service project from the main solution and created a new solution only containing the workflow service project.  After a build, the custom activities were generated and listed in the toolbox.

Comment: I had this problem in VS 2015 and needed to use this solution. I think it came down to needing the CodeActivity to be fully built before it's available to the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant for you but I had the same problem.

I could solve it like this:

- Right click on the Toolbox to open **context menu**.
- Select **Choose Items...**
- Select the tab **System.Activities Components**
- Click on **browse** and select the dll that contains the custom activity
- Make sure that the activity shows in the list and is checked
- Click **OK**

Answer (score 1):

Not really the same question but in Visual Studio 2012, on a 64 bit windows, I had a 64 bit application with CodeActivity and NativeActivity and they were not showing up in the toolbox. I changed the application to AnyCPU and built it, and the activities are now displayed...
I hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by creating a Windows Workflow 4.0 Console application and then removing out the Program.cs.  Very odd, but it worked.